# Running a script in python

Tags: python, vcf, software-usage

I am trying to run a script in python but I getting this error

```
loan-mac-13:vcf2maf fi1d18$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Feb 22 2019, 21:55:15) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.37.14)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.chdir("/Users/fi1d18/Downloads/vcf2maf-master/vcf2maf")
>>> 
>>> 
>>> os.getcwd()
'/Users/fi1d18/Downloads/vcf2maf-master/vcf2maf'
>>> vcf2maf.py -h
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'vcf2maf' is not defined
>>> python vcf2maf.py -h
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python vcf2maf.py -h
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Where I am doing wrong?

Thanks for any help

By your comments I run

Sorry says that Last login: Wed Apr  1 11:50:14 on ttys000

```
pc-133-235:~ fi1d18$ pwd
/Users/fi1d18
pc-133-235:~ fi1d18$ 
pc-133-235:~ fi1d18$ cd Downloads
pc-133-235:Downloads fi1d18$ python vcf2maf.py -h
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vcf2maf.py", line 19, in <module>
    import vcf
ImportError: No module named vcf
pc-133-235:Downloads fi1d18$
```

Comment: As I said, that's a completely separate issue. Please ask a new question about it. First, however, just copy/paste the error into your favorite search engine. That will give you the answer.

Comment: I am sorry to say, but this is a bioinformatics equivalent of "What is a cell" in biology. It appears to me that you really should go through some python tutorials to get over the basics before you proceed with your research. I heavily recommend https://software-carpentry.org/ as a starting point.

Comment: You %100 right @KamilSJaron, I am nothing in the first line of python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to run a script file in the python console. That doesn't make sense. The console is for running commands manually, interactively. A script is a collection of commands. You can't just run that by name in the console. If you want to use it, copy the *contents* of your script and try to run them in the console.

The way you run a python *script file* is simply:

```
python vcf2maf.py -h
```

Or, assuming you have made the file executable and it has the right [shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)), just:

```
./vcf2maf.py -h
```

---

The specific error you are getting is because `foo.bar` in Python means "run the `bar` method from the object `foo`. So `vcf2maf.py` means run `py` from `vcf2maf`. Since there is no object defined with the name `vcf2maf`, you get the `name 'vcf2maf' is not defined`.

Comment: Sorry says that Last login: Wed Apr  1 11:50:14 on ttys000
pc-133-235:~ fi1d18$ pwd
/Users/fi1d18
pc-133-235:~ fi1d18$ 
pc-133-235:~ fi1d18$ cd Downloads
pc-133-235:Downloads fi1d18$ python vcf2maf.py -h
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vcf2maf.py", line 19, in <module>
    import vcf
ImportError: No module named vcf
pc-133-235:Downloads fi1d18$

Comment: @Angel I can't read that. Please [edit] your question to add extra information, don't put it in the comments. And tell me who/what "says" and when. I can't guess what commands you are running. If that's the output of running the script, then it is a completely different issue, you are missing the `vcf` module. So please ask a new question about that.